# maxBuffer length exceeded error on the imagemagick identify method

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, imagemagick.net, node-imagemagick, imagemagick-identify

I try to identify a pdf of 200 pages with imagemagick but its gives me a error ' maxBuffer length exceeded'
i tried to change my policy file

i use the newest imagemagick 
i have installed ghostscript for the pdf

```
<policymap>
  <!-- <policy domain="resource" name="temporary-path" value="/tmp"/> -->
  <policy domain="resource" name="memory" value="14GiB"/>
  <policy domain="resource" name="map" value="30GiB"/>
  <policy domain="resource" name="width" value="16MP"/>
  <policy domain="resource" name="height" value="16MP"/>
  <policy domain="resource" name="area" value="40GB"/>
  <policy domain="resource" name="disk" value="100GiB"/>
  <!-- <policy domain="resource" name="file" value="768"/> -->
  <!-- <policy domain="resource" name="thread" value="4"/> -->
  <!-- <policy domain="resource" name="throttle" value="0"/> -->
 <policy domain="resource" name="time" value="99999999999999999999999999999999999999"/>
  <!-- <policy domain="system" name="precision" value="6"/> -->
  <!-- not needed due to the need to use explicitly by mvg: -->
  <!-- <policy domain="delegate" rights="none" pattern="MVG" /> -->
  <!-- use curl -->
  <policy domain="delegate" rights="none" pattern="URL" />
  <policy domain="delegate" rights="none" pattern="HTTPS" />
  <policy domain="delegate" rights="none" pattern="HTTP" />
  <!-- in order to avoid to get image with password text -->
  <policy domain="path" rights="none" pattern="@*"/>
  <policy domain="cache" name="shared-secret" value="passphrase" stealth="true"/>
</policymap>
```

maybe i forgot something or another policy i need to add i hope i have given enough information that someone can help me with this because it gives me a headache.

thanks in advance

Comment: What exact command did you run? What were you hoping to find out about the PDF?

Comment: The `maxBuffer` error is coming from the OS stdout/stderr buffer -- not ImageMagick policy. Try redirecting the output to a file.

Comment: thanks i fixed it that way